# Write one element of a list in a row at a time

Tags: python, list, csv

I have this list of list:

```
listOflist = [[123, "A", "B", "C"], [456, "D", "E", "F"], [123, "G", "H", "I"]]
```

I need to write each list in one csv file. The trick (at least for me) is I need it to be done one list at a time so I can first check if one element of the list I'm writing to the csv file is already in an other one.

The first thing I thought of is this, but it give me an error message (_csv.Error: iterable expected, not int)

```
for element in list:
    with open("test.csv", "w") as c:
    writer = csv.writer(c)
    writer.writerows(element)
```

I also tried this but it's not working properly since it only writes the last element [123, "G", "H", "I"] to the file.

```
for element in new_list:
    print(element)
    with open("test.csv", "w") as c:
        writer = csv.writer(c)
        writer.writerows(map(lambda x: [x], element))
```

Comment: In fact, you write the first list to the file. After that, you are overwriting the file with your second list. And then you overwrite it again, this time with the third list ... That is why you lose the first 2 lists.

Comment: Yeah I didn't realize I was in writing mode. I switch to append. Stupid me. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to write them to different CSV files? (By appending, you're writing to that only csv file you opened)

Comment: Yes the one and only. It worked just fine with appending. Only problem is it writes each element on a single row (and not as I wish each list on a row). Still working on it.

Answer (score 0):

`writerows` already accepts a list of lists. So you can just do:

```
with open("test.csv", "w", newline='') as c:
    writer = csv.writer(c)
    writer.writerows(listOfLists)
```

If you need to test something iterate *after building the writer*:

```
with open("test.csv", "w", newline='') as c:
    writer = csv.writer(c)
    for element in listOfLists:
        if isValid(element):     // your code testing if the list can be used
            writer.writerow(element)
```